# Windows store app - print specific div

Tags: javascript, printing, windows-store-apps

I'm wondering, if it is possible to print specific div in windows store app? I create appbar print button which call print functions, that can print whole "page"([msdn sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Print-Sample-c544cce6)). But I have to print specific visible div. Is that possible in windows store app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My div wasn't formatted as nicely as it was on the screen, but it did contain the data:

```
    onPrintTaskRequested: function (printEvent) {
    var printTask = printEvent.request.createPrintTask("Print Sample", function (args) {
        var docHtml = document.createDocumentFragment();
        docHtml.appendChild(document.getElementById("divToPrint"));
        args.setSource(MSApp.getHtmlPrintDocumentSource(docHtml));
    });
},
```

Comment: be aware thought that appendChild will remove the div from its original doc location.